# SQL Server Agent Job Invoked

Tags: sql-server

I have a job on the SQL Server Agent that reruns e.g. if the daily file load fails the SSIS package gets kicked off again.  It does not do it straight away but at strange times.  When it gets kicked off, after the failure, you can see the message:

The job succeeded.  The Job was invoked by Alert 2.  The last step to run was step1 (Run SSIS loader).

I have looked at the job and looked at the Alerts, there is nothing to indicate the how/why/what for the job rerunning.

What am I missing, something obvious I bet.

Note: I am not interested in switching the job off.  I just want to know how it is gettting rerun.  Also, I cannot find an alert called Alert 2 in the the Alerts.

Cheers

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into Job Properties -> Steps -> Job Steps -> Advanced tab?  There is a setting for the number of Retry attempts, and a Retry interval in minutes.  There is also an "On failure action" dropdown, which can be set to do unexpected things such as go on to the next step.

Alternatively, maybe is there a *different* job that is invoking this job in odd ways?  Perhaps it has a Step or a Schedule called "Alerts 2", or is called that itself?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I think the culprit is another schedule.  I am going to do standard IT procedures and switch things of and on again.  Cheers C

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution to this problem, which was that the alert was set up to start the job for some reason. After repeating the job 4 times I had to fix it.

Solution was found here: [Mystery alert keeps starting one of my jobs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/799d2824-67b2-49d8-a7c7-44280c78d5e5/mystery-alert-keeps-starting-one-of-my-jobs?forum=sqldisasterrecovery)

And in case the link disappears:

1. In SQL Server Management Studio expand the Sql Server Agent tree, and then expand Alerts.
2. Check each of the alerts properties to see if it is set to start the job by opening properties, clicking Response, and see if the job is selected in the Execute job box.
   [image]
3. Uncheck the execute job checkbox, save, and test.